# How to make the confetti background frame like this?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, background

[image: confetti background frame]

I want to make the confetti background so it looks like it is radiating out from the middle. I have tried using the scatter brush in both Photoshop and Illustrator but it looks a lot messier than this picture, and I can not just have two colours using the scatter brush.
Could someone please tell me how to do it. (it has been suggested to me by a teacher that they would have done it manually)

Comment: Could you [edit] in an image of your attempt? That may make it easier for us to help you improve your method. Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably do it with a scatter brush and just brush more around the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the symbol sprayer and various symbol tools in Illustrator. Just create a symbol for each of the different pieces of confetti or whatever it is that you have, select the symbol sprayer and spray away...

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it manually by dragging objects while holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. This will create a duplicate. It's a lot faster than using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> key combinations.

Another option is to create multiple circles in random distances from each other and add them as a new art brush. This is also a manual method, but it saves time.